# Puxar imagem do post worpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um blog em meu site, e adicionei dentro do post uma imagem através da inserção de mídia, porém, gostaria de sabe como eu puxo essa imagem da mídia através do código para inserir em outro lugar a mesma imagem.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de inserir acima do texto criação de sites em praia grande.
Ja pesquisei bastante de verdade, não estou fazendo corpo mole, mas mesmo assim não consegui achar nada ou nao fiz a pesquisa como tem que ser feito,
Fico no aguardo.
Obrigado desde já

Comment: A sua pergunta está muito vaga, mas supondo que vc queira fazer isso dentro do *loop*, acho que o caminho é usar `$media = get_attached_media( 'image' );`

Comment: Então, por que no meu site tem a página que lista todos os posts feitos e dentro de cada post desses tem uma imagem inserida através da midia.. eu quero que na pagina que liste todo os posts não tenha só o titulo e a data, tenha a imagem que contem dentro do post dele.. entendeu?

Comment: Poste o código do se loop. As coisas ficarão mais fáceis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exibição de imagens **dentro do loop** do wordpress, você pode usar a função [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/).

Caso queira pegar apenas a imagem de um determinado post fora do `loop`, use a função [`get_attached_media()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media), onde o primeiro parametro é o nome da media, `audio`, `image` e etc, e o segundo o `ID` do post.

Comment: Posha, deu certo Rafael. Muito obrigado! E se for para posts recents ou mais visitados?

Comment: @carloshsa por favor, marque minha resposta do lado esquerdo a pergunta como "resolvida", em relação aos posts mais recentes e visitados seria melhor criar uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Pronto, obrigado!